# DNS Bind9 Issue - Server not forwarding requests

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-10.04, turnkey-linux

I'm new to dns admin so please be gentle. Here is my set-up:

Domain name with a few A records points to my personal IP.
 example.com
 server1.example.com
 server2.example.com
Router forwards all port 80 requests to a Ubuntu VM box with Bind9 and Webmin installed
 Bind9 is then supposed to resolve the server1.example.com and server2.example.com
Then send them to some more VM's that host host web apps.

I *think* i have my master record set up for the domain on the Bind9 box correctly, but when go to the domain, I get the holding page for my Ubuntu VM web server and not the server1 or server2 boxes.

It appears to be getting to my Bind9 box but no further. Is this because I have the hosted DNS record on the internet and another on my internal box? or are they supposed to work together? Is it because my Bind9 isn't listening correctly?

I have been using webmin to set up the bind9, and it keeps saying all my config files are okay.

Any help, or pointers for things to look for would be gratefully received.

Comment: Which server(s) are authoritative for your domain (i.e. if your domain is example.com, what is the result of "dig @e.gtld-servers.net example.com NS") ?

Comment: Is this a public DNS server?

Comment: Bind9 listens to DNS queries on port 53 (only). It have nothing to do with HTTP queries on port 80.

Comment: Currently two ZoneEdit DNS servers are the authority as that's the service I'm using to forward to my home IP. This isn't a public DNS, its just to resolve requests behind my firewall.

Comment: Bind listens tcp/udp 53 and 953 ports by default for all interfaces unless you have changed it. you can setup a reverse proxy that redirects by host name on your UbuVM preferred way with nginx. your problem is related with network & virtual networking not with bind.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions:

1. You'll need to reconfigure your router to send the http requests to the proper web app server, and not just send them all to the Ubuntu VM box.
2. You'll need to reconfigure your Ubuntu VM box to act as a reverse proxy.  This site gives a good breakdown of how to reverse proxy with apache:  http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

What's happening is that the http request is being sent to your private IP per DNS.  Once the http hits your private IP, the request is routed to your Ubuntu VM web server.  Your Ubuntu server is listening on port 80, gets the request, and displays your page.

Comment: I assume this requires me having a smarter router than an mac airport.

Comment: Perhaps this is something i should be doing with Apache instead then? Forwarding web requests to certain submains to other IP's in my network - is this a better method?

Comment: It really depends.  If I were you, I'd look into using a reverse proxy since your router is a mac airport.